# specific number of integers

Tags: c, primes

My requirement is to print x numbers of prime integer. So my code starts off by asking user to input a number, e.g. 7, I want it to produce 7 prime numbers.

I've now coded to a step where it produces all the prime numbers that are less than 50. But how do I code it in a way that I only want it to output, in this case, 7 prime numbers ?

I've searched up but I do not understand other people's code. I will appreciate if you can edit from my code and guide me through explanation. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x,y,z;

    printf("Input a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

      for (z=2; z<=50; z++)
        {
            for (y=2; y<=z; y++)
            {
                if (z%y==0)
                    break;
            }
            if (z==y)
            printf("%d\n", z);
            
        }
}
```

Comment: Add a new counter, going from `1` to `7`. And check it when you print the numbers. Once you have printed all values break out of the outer loop.

Comment: OT: With `z<=50` you can't find more than 15 primes....

Comment: OT: If you start by printing `2` as a prime, you can start the `y` loop from `3` and increment `y` by 2

Comment: I think this code would be much more usable if you wrote a function `bool isPrime(int n)`

Comment: A more interesting question that's not really needed for this very small example is: how big is the x'th prime? This can be important for determining the sieve size for the Sieve of Eratothenes if that were the algorithm you were using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "prime number counter"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x,y,z;
    int primes = 0; // no primes found so far

    printf("Input a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

      for (z=2; z<=50; z++)
        {
            for (y=2; y<=z; y++)
            {
                if (z%y==0)
                    break;
            }
            if (z==y) {
                printf("%d\n", z);
                primes += 1; // found a prime
            }

            if (primes == x) break; // stop z loop after x primes
            
        }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `x` is the number of primes to output

Comment: May want to replace the 2..50 loop with a `while(primes < x)` in case the xth prime is larger than 50.

Comment: Good to know, thank you @Hello. I tried to make as few changes as possible so that new code could be easily detected and understood.

Comment: @pmg, I actually never thought of setting a counter and break it once it reaches x. thanks man. I understand your code 100%.